# How to preserve state of textbox and checkbox when application is closed and reopened?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net, how can I save values from a textbox and checkbox when the application is closed? When the user opens the application again, the textbox and checkbox should be filled in with the same values as before.

Do I have to save these values in a database, or what other options are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to store these settings is to use the `My.Settings` object.

Here's the documentation:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx

and here's an introductory article:

- [Using My.Settings in Visual Basic 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` file if you want to store only the value of one textbox's Text and one checkbox's Checked property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways e.g. save the options in file, or database, or anything else you find convenient. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Settings.aspx) is a article that with guide you.